# I'm trying to calculate the difference between two weeks but I'm getting a weird peak when plotting the results ( SQL / BigQuery )

Tags: sql, database, data-analysis, google-bigquery

so I have this daily table that contains the number of visitors per store, everyday.

My tables columns are:

- Date
- Store
- Number_of_Visitors
- Views : number of views of the stores' ads.

So I first started with aggregating my table to a weekly table so that I can calculate the variance between a week and the next one.

Here is how I defined variance:

```
Variance  = `Number Of Visitors in WEEK N+1 / Number of Visitors in WEEK N
```

I wrote the following query to do that (new table called: weekly)

```
SELECT
  year_week,
  min(date) as date,
  Store,
  SUM(Number_Of_Visitors) AS TOTAL_VISITORS
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    CONCAT(cast((extract(YEAR from date)), LPAD(cast((extract(WEEK from date)) as string), 2, '0') ) AS year_week
  FROM `my-project`)
GROUP BY
  year_week,  Store


  ORDER BY year_week
```

Then, in order to calculate the variance, I used the following query as well:

```
SELECT
  base.*,
  ((base.TOTAL_VISITORS-lw.TOTAL_VISITORS)/lw.TOTAL_VISITORS) AS VAR_FF,

FROM
  `weekly` base
JOIN (
  SELECT
    * EXCEPT (date),
    DATE_ADD(DATE(TIMESTAMP(date)), INTERVAL 1 Week)AS n_date
  FROM
    `weekly` ) lw
ON
  base.date = lw.n_date
  AND base.Store= lw.Store
```

When I'm plotting the variance (VAR_FF) using Data Studio and I'm  getting the following plot that doesnt 't seem to be making sense with the high peak in the middle;

[image: VAR_FF per WEEK]

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking your code should look like this:

```
SELECT date_trunc(date, week) as year_week,
       Store,
       SUM(Number_Of_Visitors) AS TOTAL_VISITORS,
       (1 - 
        (LAG(SUM(Number_Of_Visitors)) OVER (PARTITION BY Store ORDER BY MIN(date) /
         SUM(Number_Of_Visitors)
        )
       ) as VAR_FF,
FROM`my-project`
GROUP BY year_week, Store
ORDER BY year_week;
```

I'm not sure what your weird calculations for calculating the week are really doing.  This is based on the previous week in the data.

Comment: Error: Window ORDER BY expression references column date which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [5:86] (this line: ORDER BY date_trunc(date, WEEK)) . This pushes me to group by date also to avoid this error :(

Comment: Plus, I don't think we're calculating the same variance between  two weeks for same store :)

Comment: @helloworld . . . Odd that the expression is not accepted in this case.  In any case, the same functionality is provided with `MIN(date)`.